# What can these bits work on?

Tags: tools

I wonder on what kinds of things the second, third and fourth bits from the left can work?

What kinds of things can the fifth and sixth bits from the left work?

[image]

Comment: A rather fun read, actually: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_screw_drives

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Picture not really clear, but I will take a shot. From left to right:

1. socket adapter
2. looks like [torx](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torx) bit - specialty (newer version of Phillips)
3. looks like torx bit - specialty
4. looks like torx bit - specialty
5. #2 [Pozidriv](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_screw_drives#Pozidriv) - deck screws
6. #1 Pozidriv - smaller screws (curtain rods, cabinets)
7. #2 [Phillips](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_screw_drives#Phillips) - Most common
8. #1 Phillips - Most common
9. #2 [slotted](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_screw_drives#Slot) - most common
10. #1 slotted - smaller slotted screws

Comment: 1 is likely an adapter for using sockets with the screwdriver.

Comment: Yes, BMitch is right. 1 is ADP

Comment: staticsan is correct about #5 and 6= pozidriv

Comment: Does anyone actually own/use pozidriv drivers? I've never seen them at any of the bigbox stores.  I have an entire klein driver set and they don't seem to offer them either..

Comment: I corrected #5 and 6, and added links to wikipedia, hope you don't mind.

Comment: the bookshelves i just bought from ikea came with posidrive screws for the door hinges.

Comment: Here in the UK most of our regular woodscrews seem to be pozidrv (specificaly PZ2).

Comment: Phillips screws are common _in America_. In Europe most screws are Pozidriv, or (if you know what you're doing) Torx.

Answer (score 6):

The second, third and fourth bits look like [Torx](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torx) which looks like a six-pointed star. They are not the same as a simple Philips.

The fifth and sixth are [Pozidriv](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pozidriv#Pozidriv) which are largely compatible with Philips but they really shouldn't be.

Comment: Using the right bit between Pozidriv and Philips makes a huge difference - suddenly the bits no longer cam-out as badly, and for Pozidriv hardly at all (this applies both ways - use the right bit for the screw).

Answer (score 2):

The second, third and fourth bits look like are commonly used in home appliances such as notebooks, televisions, set top boxes, Xbox, apple computers/books/iPod/iPhone/ PlayStation,  but also used in Cars/Boats/ Hobby toys; in various sizes. As described in the wiki they are used for precise torque tightening in devices that require precise adjustments, for example the CD-ROM tray in an Xbox.

[image]

[image]

Because they used it inside the devices they might as well use the same screws in the covers to reduce cost of other types of screws. When they started using them some time back, people thought they were there to stop them from easily getting in and tinkering with the electronics.

But as you have experienced your self, you got all these interchangable bits in a standard screwdriver set now a days for a few bucks.

Like @staticsan mentions the Pozidriv is an improved version of the philips screwdriver.